# PyTorch: compare three tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch, comparison

I have three boolean mask tensors that I want to create a boolean mask that if the value matches in three tensors then it is `1`, else `0`.

I tried `torch.where(A == B == C, 1, 0)`, but it doesn't seem to support such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `torch.eq` operator [only supports binary tensor comparisons](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41323), hence you need to perform two comparisons:

```py
(A==B) & (B==C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
((A == B) & (B == C))
```

If required, you can always convert the boolean tensor to an appropriate type:

```
((A == B) & (B == C)).to(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the tensor is basically a NumPy array bound to the device. If not too expensive for your application and you can afford to do it on CPU, you can simply convert it to NumPy and do what you need with the comparison.